# EF Core. Как ускорить вставку несколько сот тысяч строк?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Проблема такая, через запрос rest api тригерю метод который вставляет несколько сот тысяч записей в БД, сам запрос API зависает примерно на минуту т.к. EF Core после await db.SaveChanges() вставляет все одним запросом, как можно ускорить вставку? Делить запросы не особо хочется. БД - Sql Server

Будет ли выгоднее использовать Dapper? Вставляя сразу List<>

```
public static async Task SaveList(MyClass[] list)
    {
        using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection("Server=192.168.0.20;Database=DB;User Id=sa;Password=12;"))
        {
            var query = "INSERT INTO MyClasses VALUES (@A, @B)";
            await db.ExecuteAsync(query, list);
        }
    }
```

как выяснилось dapper с таким кодом выполняет в разы дольше

Comment: Попробуйте через SqlBulkCopy: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13722014/1988244

Comment: Быстрее всего действительно с помощью SqlBulkCopy. Если не хочется вручную писать код, а хочется оставаться в рамках ORM, то я бы посоветовал перейти на [linq2db](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias). Или, если невозможно отказаться от EF, взять какую-нибудь библиотеку из списка: [EF Core Tools & Extensions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/) (искать на странице по термину "bulk"). Я бы рекомендовал linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore.

Answer (score 1):

Я посоветую использовать расширение [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) (я один из соавторов)

Все просто:

```cs
db.BulkCopy(list);
```

Вставится очень быстро.

Comment: Автору ответа и Александру Петрову - сердечное спасибо за совет!